# No values is coming during tokenizing (texts_to_sequence)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
test_sentence1 = "This is the worst flight experience of my life!"
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([test_sentence1])
print(sequences)
text = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=200)
print(text)

Output: sequences --> [[]]
```

There is no output is coming when I tokenize with text_to_sequence.

Comment: You need to **fit** your tokenizer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
test_sentence1 = "This is the worst flight experience of my life!"
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([test_sentence1]) #insert this step in your original code
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([test_sentence1])
print(sequences)
text = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=200)
print(text)
```

First you need to fit the tokenizer object on texts, before converting text to sequences.